# Is it possible to pull data from a database (MS SQL Server, Postgres, etc) directly into LaTeX?

Tags: sql, database, latex, tex

This has been bugging me for awhile now. There are various documents that, for the most part consist of a pdf with some dynamic data populated into it. This dynamic data can vary enough that the document can consist of a variable number of pages (but that extra pages are very repetitive with the same headers and so forth).

This almost seems like a job for Latex, but my searches keep coming back to the same few posts that seem almost surprised that anyone would want such a feature.

Is there a library or CTAN package for this?

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sqltex

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexdb

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nlatexdb

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatooltk

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz why not a quick reference-only answer with the four above? Pretty many indeed :)

Comment: @MattAllegro Done!

Answer (score 1):

> Disclaimer: I've never used any of the following myself, so I can't judge which one can be recommend

A quick search on ctan gives several packages about databases. Some examples:

- https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sqltex
- https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexdb
- https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nlatexdb
- https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatooltk